# Howto make GetFieldName() function

Tags: delphi

I have:

```
TMyForm = class(TForm)
strict private
  FMyColumn: TMyGridColumn;
  ...
end;

...

constructor TMyForm.Create;
begin
  ...
  FMyColumn := TMyGridColumn;
  FMyColumn.Name := 'FMyColumn';

  // I wish to substirtute it with a call like this which will return 'FMyColumn'
  FMyColumn.Name := GetFieldName(FMyColumn);
  ...
end;
```

I need to initialize the component (TMyGridColumn) name with some meaningful name but prefer to not hard-code its name as a string literal.

A non-RTTI solution will be more welcome.

Comment: do you have any idea what form the name should take?

Comment: -1 How should that be answerable? There is no algorithm that magically computes meaningful names :-/ If you provide more details and make this a useful question, I'll take the downvote back.

Comment: GetFieldName(FMyColumn) should return 'FMyColumn'. I cannot imagine GetFieldName to return something else, do you?

Comment: When saying Filed I mean the private member FMyColumn of the TMyForm class. I do NOT refer to the Dataset Field. And the grid is not data bound btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object does not have any knowledge, a priori, of which fields or variables refer to it. So without more information you can't write such a function.

If your function knew which object had a reference to the column, then it could use RTTI to find its name. Without RTTI you cannot hope to do this.

I think the fundamental problem you are having is that, although you name the function GetFieldName, you are not passing a field. You are passing an object reference.